# C# Troubleshooting the error provider -- validating text box data input

Tags: c#, error-handling, validation

everyone:

I'm trying to validate data in text boxes on a form. This is the code I have for my validator, but it's not working when I clearly violate the constraints set in the code (tabbing out of the txtbox, inputting less than 4 characters, etc. Any ideas of why this wouldn't work? The program runs, so it can't be syntax, so I suppose it must be logical error, but I just dont see it.

```
            // Validation for Applicant Name text box
    private void txtAppInfoName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

            // Define what consitiutes a match
            Match m = Regex.Match(txtAppInfoName.Text, @"\b[A-Za-z]\b");

            if (m.Success == false)
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtAppInfoName, "Please use only letters to type your name.");
                txtAppInfoName.Select();
            }

            else if (txtAppInfoName.Text.Length < 4)
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtAppInfoName, "Please type first and last names.");
                txtAppInfoName.Select();
            }

            else if (txtAppInfoName.Text == "")
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtAppInfoName, "Must enter a name.");
                txtAppInfoName.Select();
            }
            else errorProvider1.SetError(txtAppInfoName, ""); // Remove the error provider
        }
```

Comment: Did you step through your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the handler is not even called at all. Make sure the handler `txtAppInfoName_Validating` is specified in the GUI designer under the `Validating` event.

If that doesn't work, try to add a breakpoint or throw an exception in the handler and see what happens.
If it stops, you can use the call-stack to inspect the error source.

Comment: You were right. The event wasn't even being called at all. Some how, the 'validating' event had been cleared from all of the textboxes except one... the one that was working. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @INFSstudent115 These issues always used happen to me too many times and was frustrating me until I was pulling my hair out my head. As time goes by you get used to what to check first :) Please don't forget to vote / accept answer if this helped.